# In Windriver Linux how /etc/resolv.conf file gets generated?

Tags: linux, etc, resolv.conf

In Windriver Linux how /etc/resolv.conf file gets generated?

Version- 8.0, kernel version 4.1.21

And if in case when I build an image if I package resolv.conf file too will the content of it gets replaced on my actual hardware dynamically or it stays as the packaged file content

Comment: This really is not a sensible question to phrase in terms of "in Linux" and "packaged".  Operating systems and package management systems vary, in significant ways.  You need to _name your particular operating system_ in the question, not just its kernel.

Comment: Depends on many factors, the most important of which are the operating system and its version. But in general, in many, maybe in most, Linux-based operating systems `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to `/run/resolv.conf` (or some such file) which is generated *and modified* dynamically at run time by various system components having to do with network management. You really must read the documentation of the network management components *on your specific operating system*.

Comment: It depends on so many things that this question is too broad. Depends on the distribution, depends how it's configured. If you want help about your specific case, you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: This question is both a good question as well as too broadly stated... in some GNU/Linux systems running `systemd` as the init, there is a symbolic link to `/run/resolv.conf` ... in some GNU/Linux systems running `sysvinit` as the init, the `/etc/resolv.conf` contains manually entered data and configuration items... and in other other `Nix` systems there will be various configuration utilities which modify the contents either during boot or through regular use of the system.... The short answer is: **It depends**

Comment: Depends on distribution, version, and sub-version.  IE, Ubuntu 16.04 Server populates it based on dhcp info, where as Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop uses Network Manager and resolvconf and populates /etc/resolv.conf with a reference to the local machine pointing to a local-to-machine caching only DNS server that forwards requests to whatever DNS server DHCP assigned.

Comment: Are there that many systems that manage `/etc/resolv.conf`? `systemd-resolved`, `resolvconf`, NetworkManager? Which one is used (if any) depends on the distribution of course, but it should doable to list the possibilities

Comment: Its windriver linux 8.0 and kernel version is 4.1.21

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... /etc/resolv.conf generation depends on Distro + Distro version + to some extent what packages are installed + also if you're talking about at a machine level or inside an LXD container + also if you're using classic Linux networking or netplan.

This entire process is cumbersome + badly broken, which is why Debian/Ubuntu have switched to netplan.

If you're using pre-netplan (likely), then the easiest way to handle /etc/resolv.conf generation is just to disable auto generation, because tracing down the actual generation path, can take hours + also any changes you make to effect it's generation can be destroyed by future package updates.

Here's how to disable it, so any /etc/resolv.conf changes you make persist, across machine reboots or container restarts.

```
resolvconf --disable-updates
```

Comment: You should add a reference link or some reference point on what `netplan` is... apparently there is more than one program called `netplan` ... This [calendar program](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netplan) ... and also this [NetworkManager interface](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan) ... you probably mean the latter one, not the former.  Since it seems that the program you are referring to is a `systemd` interface, than it is still simply an option for configuration, and doesn't preclude use of other tools such as `systemd networkd` ... and many others...